# How to speed up requests Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request, python-requests-html

So I have this code that scrapes javascript content:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

#create the session
session = HTMLSession()

#define our URL
url = 'https://partalert.net/product.js?asin=B08L8LG4M3&price=%E2%82%AC702.07&smid=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&tag=partalertde-21&timestamp=16%3A33+UTC+%2821.4.2021%29&title=ASUS+DUAL+NVIDIA+GeForce+RTX+3070+OC+Edition+Gaming+Grafikkarte+%28PCIe+4.0%2C+8+GB+GDDR6+Speicher%2C+HDMI+2.1%2C+DisplayPort+1.4a%2C+Axial-tech+L%C3%BCfterdesign%2C+Dual+BIOS%2C+Schutzr%C3%BCckwand%2C+GPU+Tweak+II%29&tld=.de'

#use the session to get the data
r = session.get(url)

#Render the page, up the number on scrolldown to page down multiple times on a page
r.html.render(sleep=0, keep_page=True, scrolldown=0)

#take the rendered html and find the element that we are interested in
links = r.html.find('#href')

#loop through those elements extracting the text and link
for item in links:
    link = {
        'link': item.absolute_links
    }
print(link)
```

However it takes 2-3 seconds which is way to long to load for me. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: If you look at what the script in that URL does, it just parses the data from the query string you pass in, then generates an Amazon URL based on that. You should just parse the query string yourself (see `urllib.parse`), then form the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to scrape the site at all. When you look at the source code you can see that `javascript` is generating the Amazon url from the input url:

```
document.getElementById(
          "href"
        ).href = `https://www.amazon${tld}/dp/${asin}?tag=${tag}&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1&smid=${smid}`;
```

This means that you only have to replicate this function in `python` to generate your urls. You can get the values of the url parameters with `urllib.parse`, then use string formatting to generate the new url:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs

url = 'https://partalert.net/product.js?asin=B08L8LG4M3&price=%E2%82%AC702.07&smid=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&tag=partalertde-21&timestamp=16%3A33+UTC+%2821.4.2021%29&title=ASUS+DUAL+NVIDIA+GeForce+RTX+3070+OC+Edition+Gaming+Grafikkarte+%28PCIe+4.0%2C+8+GB+GDDR6+Speicher%2C+HDMI+2.1%2C+DisplayPort+1.4a%2C+Axial-tech+L%C3%BCfterdesign%2C+Dual+BIOS%2C+Schutzr%C3%BCckwand%2C+GPU+Tweak+II%29&tld=.de'
query = urlsplit(url).query
params = parse_qs(query)
amazon_url = f"https://www.amazon{params['tld'][0]}/dp/{params['asin'][0]}?tag={params['tag'][0]}&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1&smid={params['smid'][0]}"
```

Result:

```
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08L8LG4M3?tag=partalertde-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1&smid=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF
```

Comment: I have been trying to do the same with dropsentry http://dropsentry.net/product.html?JTdCJTIybiUyMiUzQSUyMkdpZ2FieXRlJTIwQU9SVVMlMjBHZUZvcmNlJTIwUlRYJTIwMzA3MCUyME1BU1RFUiUyMC0lMjBTY2hlZGElMjBncmFmaWNhJTIwZGElMjA4JTIwR0IlMjIlMkMlMjJzJTIyJTNBJTIyQW1hem9uLml0JTIyJTJDJTIycCUyMiUzQSUyMiV1MjBBQzczNy43MSUyMiUyQyUyMnUlMjIlM0ElMjJodHRwcyUzQS8vd3d3LmFtYXpvbi5pdC9kcC9CMDhMTlk4UDVMJTNGdGFnJTNEZHJvcHNlbnRyeTAxLTIxJTI2bGlua0NvZGUlM0RvZ2klMjZ0aCUzRDElMjZwc2MlM0QxJTI2c21pZCUzREExMUlMMlBOV1lKVTdIJTIyJTJDJTIydCUyMiUzQTE2MTkwMzY1NjM4NjYlN0Q= but I am not able to locate the var needed.

Comment: https://ibb.co/g7M9f73
Thats the only things i have found in dropsentry

Comment: That's a different case. Here the Amazon url is `base64` encoded in the url. Try `import base64`, then `base64.b64decode(url_variable_here.split('?')[1]).decode("utf-8")`.

Comment: `from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qs
import base64
url = 'http://dropsentry.net/product.html...'
result = base64.b64decode(url.split('?')[1]).decode("utf-8")
print(result)`

Okay so I wrote this code and I got this as the output 

`%7B%22n%22%3A%22Gigabyte%20AORUS%20GeForce%20RTX%203070%20MASTER%20-%20Scheda%20grafica%20da%208%20GB%22%2C%22s%22%3A%22Amazon.it%22%2C%22p%22%3A%22%u20AC737.71%22%2C%22u%22%3A%22https%3A//www.amazon.it/dp/B08LNY8P5L%3Ftag%3Ddropsentry01-21%26linkCode%3Dogi%26th%3D1%26psc%3D1%26smid%3DA11IL2PNWYJU7H%22%2C%22t%22%3A1619036563866%7D`

Comment: it kinda worked because if I see the output closely it outputs also "www.amazon.it/dp/B08LNY8P5L%3Ftag%3Ddropsentry01-21%26linkCode%3Dogi%26th%3D1%26psc%3D1%26smid%3DA11IL2PNWYJU7H" But what does this other stuff mean?

Comment: Try this to create a clean url: `amazon_url = 'https://' + base64.b64decode(url.split('?')[1]).decode("utf-8").split('//')[1]`